# Vue.js: position div below link

Tags: vue.js

I have a bunch of dynamic *Links* created in *Vue.js*

`<a class="block" href="#" @click="toggleNavigation(item)" v-for="item in skills" :key="item.id">{{item.name}}</a>`

and a *Div* that is positioned *absolute*

```
<div style="position:absolute; width:300px">some text </div>
```

If I click on a link I would like to position the div below the clicked link.

How can I get the clicked link's properties in Vue? In javascript I would do something like this:

```
document.getElementById(this).style.top
```

Here is a fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/sqe0rpnk/6/

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/vuejs-find-elements-by-model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the `$event` variable along side your params, as:

```
@click="toggleNavigation($event, item)"
```

Now, in your `toggleNavigation` you can access the clicked HTML's attributes, classes, value ... as:

```
methods: {
 toggleNavigation (event, item){
  console.log(event)
 }
}
```